# Should reviewing shader code be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

While there is already a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site, there aren't many questions there about shader code, and I feel that those kinds of questions would attract more attention here.

Should reviewing shader code be on-topic?

Comment: Just IMHO; I suppose this would depend on what aspect we're trying to improve it for. If it needed to run faster, I would put it on Code Review, but if it didn't look right, I'd say it would work here better. Maybe a discussion for chat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm tempted to say yes, due to the fact that there's only about 5 such questions on Code Review. But on the other hand, that site is the correct place to ask questions on **how to improve working code**. As an active user of CR, I'd also like to see more questions relating to shaders over there, so I'm a bit biased.

I think if the code is working and the user is looking to make it cleaner / better / more concise, It belongs to Code Review. Questions asking for suggestions on how to improve efficiency or performance of shaders would also be a fit for CR, but I doubt these questions would find a lot of help on that regard over there at the current stage. The site just doesn't have enough reviewers that are comfortable with shader optimizations.

So disagreeing with @robobenklein's comment, reviews looking to improve performance are a better fit in here, optimizing shaders is an expert area. Making code more readable / maintainable / scalable is definitely a Code Review topic for any language.

Comment: Whilst I generally agree, I think we should be cautious on allowing "performance reviews". IMO, questions that ask for re-design of an algorithm accompanied with a shader code snippet should be welcome, but question a-la "here's my code, make it faster", asking basically for micro-optimization or free work shouldn't really.

Comment: @cifz, yes, absolutely. Good point!