# Should we tag review questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Consensus is leaning towards a yes to [Should code review questions be considered on topic?](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223/should-code-review-questions-be-considered-on-topic)

Would it be useful to have a [review](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review) tag to apply to such questions? If so I imagine questions being subject to similar restrictions as on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), so for example the tag would only be applied if the code is already working. The tag wiki would then give us a place to define the requirements for a code review computer graphics question.

Comment: My first thought is that we shouldn't introduce a [tag:review] tag. Why would anyone especially search for review questions? Maybe it would even be a meta tag. It doesn't add anything to a question, nor would such a question be "about review".

Comment: The best place to define the requirements would be here on the meta site. This is the discussion zone for our site and we have a [meta-tag:faq] meta-tag that we can fill as needed.